# How to modify the way a ForeignKey field is rendered in a Django admin page to avoid browser crash?

Tags: django, firefox, django-admin, crash

I have a Customer model which contains a ForeignKey to a Contact model.

I have over 100,000 contacts in my DB and when I load the admin page for a specific customer, the dropdown menu for the contact is getting populated with ALL of the contacts in the database. This has recently, due to its shear length, started causing my Firefox to crash while the admin page is loading.

Is there a way to either:

1. replace the field with an integer
   field I can manually modify to the
   contact ID when necessary
2. replace the dropdown menu with some
   alternative input method which won't
   crash the browser
3. remove this input
   from the Customer admin page
   altogether

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do *any* of the *either of* things you want to.

Simplest solution is the exclude the field from the admin. Just [say so](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.exclude) in the admin class.

You can change the field to be text input and display it's primary key rather than the item itself, by including it in the `raw_id_fields` of the admin class.

You can also replace the standard dropdown widget with the Auto complete text field input. Use the [implemented widget](http://jannisleidel.com/2008/11/autocomplete-form-widget-foreignkey-model-fields/), or other equivalents. - This is probably the solution you like the best.

You can also override the `formfield_for_foreignkey` method on the `Admin` model to customize the queryset that gets displayed in the foreign-key dropdown. You may want to checkout [my implementation](http://github.com/becomingGuru/django-subdomain-admin/blob/master/subdomain_admin/admin.py) for displaying only the current User's (or subdomain's) added entities.

Comment: +1 for autocomplete. does it generate all the data for the autocomplete up-front and just not display it all at once, or does it dynamically access information somehow else? (the latter would sound strange to me)

Comment: eruciform, Autocomplete widget uses AJAX requests to complete the entity `__unicode__` on the fly, or so I think.

Comment: Thoroughly answered, Lakshman. You hit all the points I would have!

Comment: please reply . i need to know how this implemented widget is used.. the tag is not working what is the code .

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like specifying the `contact` field in `raw_id_fields` in your admin.py entry for the relevant model would sort you out. Docs are [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#raw-id-fields).

PS. Surprised (but not that surprised) that FF gives out before your database server tanks...